Virtializing single guest in multiple hosts
I'm not sure if this question is more adequate to be asked here, in Super User or Unix Exchange but this seemed like the best forum to me.
I'm used to virtualizing several VM's in a single host. I have a small odroid N2+ cluster in my house and I'm curious to know if I can in any way produce a single OS that runs in more than one node. For example, to run an application that consumes more than the available 4GB RAM per-node.
I found hadoop and MPI, but both seem to be programming models, not tools to virtualize OS's. I also never heard of anything similar in KVM, VirtualBox, VMWare or QEMU.
Is there any way to do this?
Maybe in other words what I want to ask is: is there such a thing as a MPI implementation of linux? Or is this a fantasy dreamt only by the utterly deranged?

Yes, there are/were things like Open Mosix and OpenSSI that sort of presented a single operating system that spans multiple hosts. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-system_image for one such  concept. Other techniques for scaling applications beyond the resources of a single host gained more traction.

I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you post this as an answer, @HBruijn?

It sounds like you're considering a distributed operating system and/or a single system image (SSI)cluster.
The fact that you don't see such functionality is because nowadays most people and organisations solve resource and  availability requirements  that need to scale beyond the resources of a single host  differently, in a less complex manner than a SSI cluster.
There are/were Linux and/or  OpenSource projects  like openMosix and OpenSSI that sort of presented a single operating system that spans multiple hosts.
Wikipedia suggests that OpenVMS / VMSCluster is the more or less the only remaining actively maintained SSI solution.

Weird... I would assume that creating an OS that generalizes the usage of several nodes would be useful enough to have a bunch of active implementations. But maybe the end result of having a SSI over two uni-core nodes is not as good as having one system over a dual-core node, for example?
I feel like the only way to actually know is by experimenting anyway...

Yes, but implementation is quite complex. If 99.99% of the whole customer base doesn’t need such a functionality, and 0.01% who need aren’t ready to pay big $$$ for it… The writing is on the wall, mate, what happens next!
